# Using keyof with a generic function and a newable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a function that looks like this:

```
export function getModel<T extends object>(model: new () => T, properties: { [key: keyof T]: any }): T {

}
```

The issue that I am having is that `key` errors saying:

> An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.

Basically what this is supposed to do is take a class reference, and you should be able to pass a list of the properties that are in the class reference to the second parameter.

```
export class A {
  public b: string;
  public c: boolean;
}

getModel(A, { b: 'cat', c: false});
```

So, What I would like is for the keys to be a list of the properties in the class within the object. How can this be done?

Comment: You want a [mapped type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and not an index signature.  Maybe `{[K in keyof T]: any}`, which is the same as `Record<keyof T, any>`.  Or maybe you just want `T` or `Partial<T>`, since the object you're passing looks like it has the same properties as `A`.

Comment: @jcalz Like 30 seconds after I posted this I found that `{[K in keyof T]: any}` is what I wanted.

Comment: I wonder: [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/PTAEAcCcHtwU0gFwJZwM4C5QG8DaBpUZAO1AGs4BPaAM1ABUBdLAQ2MoF8BYAKBFBYBjQXHCI0OUACMsAIkEtEsgDShBWGiwA2aOKA6qhIsROzSsARlXrQAJn2rIcAFZxB4yTNDzFs-b15+KFgEFHQsemVAsCNRDzMvHyVrDW1dB1AnV3dTc1ArNSx7A0yXN3i8pL9uHmiIGHgkVExQAAUWJu0AHnoAPlU62JNPOQVkwtBNHT0SrPLcrwKbYsNhOIXR339anjgAD3BoJEmAV2J3ZGhSAHM4RABZaAATOC0e0H3EOGIniWgpbKIXoACl4oFAAFtnq8sMQ4AB3UDAgCUoAAvL0GKpgo0wi16MiIjgwaVECdIKQAPIA8oAOhYaDQyGuxGBcMRUJeWhR2IaoWayIA3Lwarx9odjoItAyJABBYk8cHgE5SLTIQR5NCISAka7o7wkZAobTIABecHucFkwsVEBVao1Nik0GgWjgbH1U10NtFPFuD2h3NlqgSWAA5GMwylJmkZkKgA)